# How to specify the ticket form in Zendesk Support when using passControll API of Sunshine Conversations?

Tags: bots, whatsapp, zendesk

I have a whatssapp bot that is integrated to my zendesk account via sunshine, we have a ticket form exclusive for bot calls but the passControll API doesnt create the ticket in the correct form when called.

I tried multiple alternatives in the body of the request, such as: `dataCapture.systemField.form_id`, `dataCapture.systemField.ticket_form_id`, `dataCapture.ticketField.form_id` and `dataCapture.ticketField.ticket_form_id` and even passing the ID of the form as a custom field, none worked and it kept creating the tickets in the standard form. I wonder if its possible to select the form or it will always go to the standard one?

Comment: As far as I understand the documentation, it should be `"dataCapture.systemField.ticket_form_id": <integer>`
However, when I tested passing control to zd-agentWorkspace, I always got 400 response with error code `switchboard_invalid_target` and a `cannot connect` message from answerbot. What are you getting in response?
Workaround: set the correct form using Zendesk triggers.

Comment: I opened a ticket on their helpdesk and got informed that it's not possible to pass the form via the API, so I'm currently working with triggers and automations to solve it, not ideal but it's the only available option at the moment. I never got a 400 response, always a 201 and the ticket was created with no issues, except in the wrong form.

Answer (score 0):

Update: according to Zendesk it's not possible to do so, the recommended alternative is to use triggers and/or automations to manipulate the ticket form after it is created.